# Cannot access user files with root using osxfuse

Tags: macos, ssh

I mounted external server via sshfs root@example.com but I cannot access user files (ie someuser:somegroup) that have no permissions set for other (ie drwx--x--x. 17 graphica:graphica foldername).

There is no problem accessing this folder via ssh or sftp when I access the server as root.

Shouldn't sshfs have the same root privileges as ssh?

Answer (score 3):

I just found the solution.

I was missing -o defer_permissions from my command

The following post has more info in this topic:

https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems/issues/1#issuecomment-3612902

Comment: This helped indeed unlike the `allow_other` option.